# Sort data using sort function or sort as retrieved from database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have a list of teams with corresponding scores.

`$name[$i]` contains the names while `scores[$i]` contains the corresponding scores

I need to sort the teams by score while maintaining a scores association with it's corresponding team name.

I am wondering is it best to create a multidimensional array such as
`$teaminfo[$name][$score]` and use a sort function or am I better off 
sorting the data as it is grabbed from the database using sql?

Does it even matter which way? I am looking for the simplest way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll save yourself a whole world of headaches by sorting it direct from the database. Just include a `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL.

EDIT:

If currently running 2 queries then

```
SELECT first_table.*, second_table.* WHERE first_table.id = second_table.id 
ORDER BY second_table.score DESC
```

(or whatever!)

Comment: Ok, but I was wondering, lets say if I retrieve `score` will I not have to then reassign the ordered values to their corresponding `name` by running another database check? or is it possible to do all in one go?

Comment: Are you running 2 queries? If so group the queries (see my edit).

Comment: At the moment yes. I just found this after googling. It does exactly what I want...http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlorderby.php

Comment: Lol pretty sure that's what I suggested. Anyway hope it's working now.

Comment: Yep, it was, I just wanted to see an example. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Josh's answer....

> I need to sort the teams by score...a multidimensional array such as $teaminfo[$name][$score]

WTF? If a team can only have one score why try to keep a single value in an array? You only need a simple array (BTW: PHP arrays aren't multi-dimensional - they're nested):

```
$s=mysql_query("SELECT team, score FROM yourtable");
while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($s)) {
   $data[$r['team']]=$r['score'];
}
arsort($data);
```

However it will be much faster to sort the data in the database before returning it to PHP. OTOH it's possible that you may have multiple values for $score for each $team - and we don't know how these are combined to determine order - by max value? by average? total? something else? In which case you may need a subquery.